# Modeling 4 people going to same place over 3 different places for at least 5 days

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I'm trying to model a linear programming task with the condition 4 people going to the same place among 3 different places for at least 5 days. I have the variables for the time spend each person in each city and the binary variables telling if each person goes to each citie.

My approach was sometihng related to multiplying the binary variables, but then i reallized that if we have variable multiplications we would not be talking about a linear task.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using binary variables, you should be able to replicate the multiplication through addition. For e.g. If binary variables, $xyz=1 \iff x+y+z=3$

Comment: Yep, but how do i then to state an or condition? IF they go all to place 1 OR place 2 OR place 3? Because i was using the addition as an equivalent of that one